# AndroidViewClient throwing TRANSPORT NOT SET ERROR

Tags: androidviewclient

I've been working with the adbClient.py from AndroidViewClient.
I've run across the following error thrown occasionally and not sure how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/damonh/projects/prodtests/tablet/test_homePage.py", line 15, in <module>
print adb.getSdkVersion()
File "/Users/damonh/projects/prodtests/tablet/adbClient.py", line 541, in getSdkVersion
self.__checkTransport()
File "/Users/damonh/projects/prodtests/tablet/adbClient.py", line 312, in __checkTransport
raise RuntimeError("ERROR: Transport is not set")
RuntimeError: ERROR: Transport is not set
```

an example would be:  getSdkVersion()

Here is my test code:

```
import adbClient
adb=adbClient.AdbClient()
print adb.getSdkVersion()
```

This is just one.  Another would be the shell method.  Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If you show more about the script perhaps I can help you. Are you taking screenshots?

Comment: I am using the adbClient.py from your library to import from.  The test code I have above is all I am doing.  If I try adb.wake I get the same thing.
What is TRANSPORT and what should it be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you script was just an example, but if it's the real one you are missing the serialno parameter to `AdbClient` and that's why the transport is not set.

You should do

```
import adbClient
adb=adbClient.AdbClient(serialno='.*')
print adb.getSdkVersion()
```

or replace by whatever regular expression or serial number you are intending to use.

To be able to communicate with a specific device, `adb` should set the transport using `'host:transport:<serialno>'`, then if the serialno is `None` (default value) it cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I do have another issue which I will post once I get good info.  Seems a child activity is not able to be accessed.  Even though culebra is returning all the info I should need.  Thanks for building this wonderful library!